# Selecting a representative graph

Tags: regression, clustering

I have a bunch of graphs that if one looks at them can see that they share a clear trend. My question is how to pick a representative graph? Would it make sense to standardize all curves first and then fit an equation using regression?

[image]

Comment: Giving example figures would help others understand your purpose better

Comment: Thanks @gunes, I have added a figure.